# ngAnimate in AngularUI modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-animate

Are there limitations when using ngAnimate inside an AngularUI modal that is bound via templateUrl?

I could not get the animation to work *inside* the modal. Show & Hide of course work, just without animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone:

New modal window is appended to the end of `<body>`.

If the root element of application is `<body>` or `<html>` everything works fine. But if the root of application is any tag in the `<body>`, animation will not work in the modal.

Here is a [not working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qw2uKaEh1zpeECys4clv?p=preview) and a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jv5NnoWVrxuj46aCBkEz?p=preview).

Comment: Please include the link text in here as well.

Comment: Clicking the two links today - both behave identically FWIW

Comment: Perfect! I would have never figured that out in a million years.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, 
another workaround is to use appendTo option of uibModal.